# Grunt-like tool for ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, gruntjs, server

Is there something like Grunt that works for ASP.NET Web API?

Grunt is an excellent test tool, you can serve your web apps live by using:

```
grunt serve
```

Afterwards, any edits made are automatically pushed to your test site.

Is there something like this in .NET?
When you change something, it auto-compiles and then creates a new instance in IIS Express.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out [BrowserLink](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)? Of course it requires VS 2013, but you can get Community Edition for free.

ASP.NET vNext goes even further,

http://www.asp.net/vnext

Powered by Roslyn you get instant compilation.

Comment: But I can only edit HTML, JS and CSS code with BrowserLink.

Comment: (continuation) I cannot edit the compiled code (C#). I want something that automatically compiles C# code and pushes it directly to the test page.

Comment: Only ASP.NET 5 aka vNext supports what you want but it is not yet finalized.